# Building a Docker Image via compose results into a new image. why?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

Building the repository of code always results into a new image, while it should replace/update the exiting image.
How can i rebuild the same image after making changes in the source files,
I am building a container image via  command.

```
    $docker-compose up --build
```

the response is as :

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/var/lib$ docker images
REPOSITORY     TAG        IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
nodeapi_www   latest     74378f9c5de5        5 seconds ago       684.3 MB
none          none       d358efc16f16        About an hour ago   684.3 MB
node          4.4.1      4e2e99ae7d3e        5 weeks ago         643.8 MB
```

here is the  image was webapp image, before i run the docker-compose up --build command. After which i get an orphan image here in the image's list.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the nature of the way docker works, if you make any changes you will need a new image, since images don't change like containers do.

Try doing the following when doing your build, and see if that helps remove the older images.

```
$ docker-compose up --build --remove-orphans
```

If you don't want to have so many images, look at using volumes so that the items that are changing are in the volume and you don't need to rebuild every time you change one of those files.

To see an example of this, look at https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/ it isn't node.js but the idea is the same.

Comment: Hi Ken, I've tried running it with  '--remove-orphans' however i didn't actually worked for me, i got an other orphan image.  However i'll appreciate volume  thing as it was also needed  i.e, ( not to build everything manually, it should pick each change automatically)

Comment: Actually there is still no solution for that, whenever a build is held there is always a new image in the docker image's list. We need to remove them manually. However thank you. and now i am going to get into the concept of volumes for a specific container, which would probably be helpful.